Query on Handling Structural Breaks in Time Series Data for Prediction Using Supervised Machine Learning
Will structural breaks in commodity prices(Raw Data)  impact the prediction accuracy of machine learning models?
If the answer is yes, I would greatly appreciate your guidance on the following aspects:
Identification: How can we determine whether the time series data contains structural breaks?
Mitigation/Removal: What steps can we take to address structural breaks before proceeding with prediction?
Your insights on this matter would be invaluable to my research.
